# Change the font color of one element in bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the font color of a link in a bootstrap navbar when certain conditions apply. However, it seems that the default font color for navbar links is used regardless if I apply a new CSS rule.

I have set up a bootply to illustrate my approach:

[example](http://www.bootply.com/q6k7B9vbkY)

I am using bootstrap 2.3.2. Is it possible to change the font color of just one element in a bootstrap navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://www.bootply.com/9yBRIJlqT0#)

```
<div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a class="red" href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
.red
{
    color:#ff0000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For one or more links to have different colors than the rest of the page:

There are two methods for doing this:

1.)Placing font tags between the ` and the  tag.
This method will work on all browsers except MSIE 3.

2.)Using a style setting in the  tag. 
This method works on MSIE3 and newer browsers.

The first technique would look like this:

```
<a href="#"><font color="FF00CC">HOME</font></a>
```

The second technique would look like this:

```
<a href="#" style="color: rgb(0,255,0)">HOME</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To define colors for all links on the page:

The general color of text links is specified in the `<body>` tag, like in the example below:

`<body link="#C0C0C0" vlink="#808080" alink="#FF0000">`

link - standard link - to a page the visitor hasn't been to yet. (standard color is blue - #0000FF).

vlink - visited link - to a page the visitor has been to before. (standard color is purple - #800080).

alink - active link - the color of the link when the mouse is on it. (standard color is red - #FF0000).